# Can I make xdebug stop\break on exceptions ? (Ubuntu/Netbeans IDE/PHP 5.4/CLI/xdebug)

Tags: php, xdebug

I am runnig PHP CLI application.

If I set a breakpoint, xdebug stops on it. if I write `xdebug_break();` it stops as well.

Can I make it stop if application throws an exception?

My ini file:

php -i | grep php.ini
Loaded Configuration File => **/etc/php5/cli/php.ini**

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be a bit late to the game, but you could use:

```
function my_exception_handler(Throwable $e) {

  if (function_exists('xdebug_break') )
    xdebug_break();

  die('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage() );

} // Function //
  
set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');
```

As it states in the xdebug documentation:

> **bool xdebug_break()**
>
> *Emits a breakpoint to the debug client.*
>
> This function makes the debugger break on the specific line as if a
> normal file/line breakpoint was set on this line.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with xdebug alone however in php you can use the set_exception_handler to register a function that catches uncaught exceptions. You can then place a breakpoint in that function.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

You can do the same for errors:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php